# Calculate the number of vowels and consonants in a word

Tags: unix, shell, scripting, ubuntu

I want to calculate the number of vowels and consonants in a word in a shell script, but I'm not sure how I can run through the word. Can anyone help me?
What I so far have is:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Give a word'

read word

case $word
in
        a*|e*|i*|o*|u*)
                vowels=&((klinker + 1 ))
        ;;
        *)
                consonants=&((medeklinker + 1 ))
        ;;
esac

echo $vowels
echo $consonants
```

Comment: What are you after?  A count of the vowels in a word, and a count of the consonants?

Comment: yes thats right, but i know in c++ how i can walk through the word but in unix i don't know that sow how can i walk through the word that is the big question :P

Comment: First you have to define what you mean by consonant and vowel.  The letter Y is cleary a vowel in words like *shy* and *byte* and *Bryce*, whereas it is a semiconsonant in *yellow* and *Yale* and a semivowel in *boy* and *they*. The R in *acre* is obviously a vowel, while the L in *little* is clearly a consonant at the start of the word but a vowel at the end. The N in *nth* is clearly a vowel, and even such in *eaten*.  Even S can be a a vowel, as it is in *psst*.  Shall we discuss the word *cwm*, where W is obviously that words vowel?

Comment: @tchrist: Can you cite a source for 'the R in acre is a vowel', which is not an obviously true assertion to me (in fact, it is contentious and seems wrong to me). (See [Is 'of course' just a warning that something is not obvious?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37805/is-of-course-just-a-warning-that-something-is-not-obvious).)  Similarly for the discussions of L, N and S.  The W in (Welsh) _cwm_ is a double-u rather literally; I'd agree that there, it is acting as a vowel.

Comment: @Jonathan Given that **a vowel is a sound that occurs as a syllabic center…** Consider 2-syllable words like *little* and *acre*. I believe we’ll agree on their 1st syllables. Discard their final E’s because silent letters play no part in syllables. C and T are stops, not continuants, and so can’t be held to form a syllabic center. That leaves nothing but R&L as their respective syllable’s vowel. Another easily deduced example is *class’s*: an apostrophe is always silent, leaving the final S to be the 2nd syllable’s vowel. *Psst* has 1 syllable: P&T are stops, leaving only S for its vowel. Qᴇᴅ

Comment: @Jonathan I see I forgot N. Consider the two-syllable word *didn’t*. The first syllable is *did*, leaving *n’t* for the second syllable.  The apostrophe doesn’t count because as always it is silent and so cannot contribute to a syllable.  The T is a stop and so cannot be held, and if you cannot hold it as you like, it cannot be a syllabic center. The only letter left is N, which means it is **necessarily** that syllable’s vowel; there is no alternative.  Convinced yet? :)

Comment: don't forget, 'y' is sometimes a vowel...(so none of these are correct answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to count the number of vowels and number of consonants, and that the shell is `bash`, what about:

```
word=abstemiously
vowels=$(echo $word | sed 's/[^aeiou]//g')
consonants=$(echo $word | sed 's/[aeiou]//g')

echo "${#word} characters"
echo "${#vowels} vowels"
echo "${#consonants} consonants"
```

Output:

```
12 characters
5 vowels
7 consonants
```

You could compress the processing, and you could use `tr` instead of `sed`.  There are also, in Bash 4.x at least, substitution operations in the shell that might be usable so you don't have to run an external program (such as `tr` or `sed`) at all.  You also need to think what happens to punctuation, digits and spaces (generically, non-letters).  Again, there are multiple ways to deal with such issues.

Comment: thanks, i have the answer of mine previous comment thank you for the help this was the perfect answer, know when i think logical it seems obvious

Comment: The OU in *abstemiously* is a digraph that represents a single phoneme, and not even a diphthong at that. In any event, there is only one syllable there. Similarly, *squeeze* in a single syllable whose syllablic center is in writing represented by the EE digraph, which is a single sound and so a single vowel. The U and the final E are both silent, and having no sound at all clearly cannot be vowels. Although the Z is not here a vowel, it can be a vowel in other words, such as *bzzzt!*; see above for why.

Answer (score 1):

```
vowels=`echo $word | tr -cd 'aeiou' | wc -c`
```

Comment: You need to provide some input to `tr` (not least so the user does not have to enter the word twice).  Also, using backticks is generally a bad idea - use the `$(tr ... | wc -c)` notation.

Comment: both forms of command substitution seem fine to me.. the differences are very marginal.

Comment: If I need to change directory to the `lib` directory for my current version of Perl, I definitely prefer `cd $(dirname $(dirname $(which perl)))/lib` to the equivalent using backticks (which I can't even begin to type in MarkDown for comments; it is bad enough in plain shell).  You need triple backslashes.  (Using % in place of backticks, the equivalent is: `cd %dirname \%dirname \\\%which perl\\\%\%%/lib`.)  Without nesting, there isn't much difference; with nesting, the difference is vast!

Comment: I know. do you see a nesting here? :)

Comment: No: but consistency suggests putting back-ticks in the category of 'legacy syntax' best left unused by people learning shell from scratch today.

Comment: ok, I will take that into consideration when giving others help.

Answer (score 0):

just with bash:

```
letters=${word//[^[:alpha:]]/}     # remove all whitespace, punctuation, etc
cnsnnts=${letters//[aeiou]/}       # remove vowels
num_consonents=${#cnsnnts}
num_vowels=$(( ${#letters} - $num_consonents ))
```

Answer (score 0):

#A very Simple Program to count vowels and consonants:

read word
**v=`echo $word | tr -cd 'aeiou' | wc -c`

c=`echo $word | tr -cd 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz' | wc -c`**
echo "vowels = $v"
echo "consonants =  $c"